# VBA Coding Issues for Arrays to Create New Workbooks

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Okay, I did not get any responses to my prior posts, maybe because my coding was so convoluted. I have addressed most of the issues from my prior posts, however, I have one issue that I am still battling. When the user selects multi items from my listbox (Me.Submissionlist) the array isn't recognized. Instead, the program produces two worksheets: selections for index 0 and 1. I need the multiselect to reference the array in the code and bring in ONE new workbook that produces the array noted in the code. Please help me. Here is the code (I intalicized the issue):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CMDSubSelector_Click()
  SubmissionSelector.Hide
  On Error Resume Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  Dim wbNew As Workbook
  Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim selCount As Integer
  selCount = -1

  With Me.Submissionlist
    For i = 0 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
      If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(i) = True Then
        Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Client_Profile", "SubmissionProperty")).Copy
        Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
        Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
      End If
      Exit For
    Next i

    If selCount = -1 Then
      Me.Submissionlist.Selected(i) = False
      Me.Submissionlist.Clear
      With Me.Submissionlist
        For i = 1 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
          If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(i) = True Then
            Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = False
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Client_Profile", "SubmissionLiabilty")).Copy
            Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = True
            Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
            Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
          End If
          Exit For
        Next

        If selCount = -1 Then
          Me.Submissionlist.Selected(i) = False
          Me.Submissionlist.Clear
          With Me.Submissionlist
            Dim Select1, Select2 As Integer
            For Select1 = 0 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
              If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True Then
                For Select2 = 1 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
                  If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True Then
                    If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select2) = True Then
                      Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1 And Select2) = True
                      Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = False
                      Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = False
                      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Client_Profile", "SubmissionProperty", "SubmissionLiabilty")).Copy
                      Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = True
                      Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = True
                      Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
                      Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
                    End If
                    Exit For
                  End If

                  If selCount = -1 Then
                    Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = False
                    Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select2) = False
                    Me.Submissionlist.Clear
                    If Me.Submissionlist.Value Then Unload Me
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                  End If
                Next
              End If
            Next
          End With
        End If
      End With
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the sample details about the items present in the listbox, their selection status, expected output and actual output?

Comment: The list box contain 14 items. Each item produces a new workbook as defined by the array.

Comment: but all your `For ... Next` kill itself at the first loop... doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: So, each item brings in existing worksheets into a new workbook that is generated to clients. The Client_Profile worksheet is always included in all selections, upon which other worksheets vary depending on the single or multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code:

```
    ....
    Dim Select1, Select2 As Integer
    For Select1 = 0 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
      If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True Then
        For Select2 = 1 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
          If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True Then
            If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select2) = True Then
              Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1 And Select2) = True
              Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = False
              Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = False
              ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Client_Profile", "SubmissionProperty", "SubmissionLiabilty")).Copy
              Sheets("SubmissionProperty").Visible = True
              Sheets("SubmissionLiabilty").Visible = True
              Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
              Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
            End If
            Exit For '<~~~ will always be activated
          End If
          If selCount = -1 Then
            Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = False
            Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select2) = False
            ....
```

the second cycle will only be started if `Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True` which is ok, but the first `If` in the second cycle is: `If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select1) = True Then` which is always `true` due to the fact that only having it being `true` can lead to this point. And now comes something I do not understand at all: after your `If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(Select2) = True Then` (which itself still is is ok) there is an `Exit For` (I skipped the second one). Knowing that the first `If` in the second circle always will be `true`, it will also always kill the second loop at the first cycle.... no matter what. 'I don't think you want it this way...

Same goes for your:

```
For i = 0 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1
  If Me.Submissionlist.Selected(i) = True Then
    ....
  End If
  Exit For '<~~~ will always be activated
Next i
```

It eliminates itself at the first cycle...

**EDIT**: While I still don't know what you desire exactly, I created 2 subs which may help you:

---

This one creates 1 new workbook for each item which is selected (holding the selected item and "SubmissionProperty")

```
Private Sub CMDSubSelector_1_Click()
  SubmissionSelector.Hide
  Dim subArr As Variant
  subArr = Array("SubmissionProperty", "SubmissionLiabilty", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
  Dim i As Long
  With Me.Submissionlist
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(i) = True Then
        Sheets(subArr(i)).Visible = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Client_Profile", subArr(i))).Copy
        Sheets(subArr(i)).Visible = True
        Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
        Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
      End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

---

This one creates only one new wb holding "SubmissionProperty" and all selected items from your list

```
Private Sub CMDSubSelector_2_Click()
  SubmissionSelector.Hide
  Dim subArr As Variant
  subArr = Array("SubmissionProperty", "SubmissionLiabilty", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
  Dim subCol() As Variant
  ReDim subCol(0)
  subCol(0) = "Client_Profile"
  Dim i As Long
  With Me.Submissionlist
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(i) = True Then
        ReDim Preserve subCol(0 To UBound(subCol) + 1)
        subCol(UBound(subCol)) = subArr(i)
      End If
    Next i
    Sheets(subCol).Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(subCol).Copy
    Sheets(subCol).Visible = True
    Worksheets("Client_Profile").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)
    Worksheets("Client_Profile").Activate
  End With
End Sub
```

---

Hopefully this helped you a bit :)

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that I was stopping the event and refreshing to begin a new event. I am new to coding and I still misunderstand a lot of terms. I should lose the Exit For?

Comment: If I remove the Exit For. The activity produces multiple workboooks for single selections. When I place the Exit For back, the single selections recognize the array and produce one workbook that represent the array. In regard to the multiple selections it does not recognize the array with or without the Exit For. –

Comment: @Liz I see multiple `With Me.Submissionlist
        For i = 1 To Me.Submissionlist.ListCount - 1` loop which might be creating multiple workbooks

Comment: Oh, okay. I will adjust this and see what happens. Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nimesh, I removed With Me.Submissionlist from every line of the code and I still get the same results with the array for the multiselect being ignored and producing the worksheets for index 0 and index 1.

Comment: I'll look into that as good as possible... may take a while (without sample-data)

Comment: Thanks so much Dirk Reichel!

Comment: @Liz the more I look at the code, the more i get confused... if I select item 9 in the list, what sheet do you expect to be copied? is is `Sheet(9)` or it `item(9).value` the sheetname?

Comment: I am in level one of the prototype, the presentation calls for items 0 and 1 for right now. So, this is my focus on coding. I have not coded past property and liability. I can continue the coding once I get a handle on at least two items.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that at first. For now, I am attempting to lock in the code and from there I will build out the remaining items.

Comment: @Liz Please read my edit and just write a comment if you have left any questions :) (be careful, i changed the sub-names)

Comment: I will try both edits now.Thank you so much!!! I will let you you know what happens. Thank you for responding!!!!

Comment: @DirkReichel Please review my response and thanks so much in your continued assistance!

Comment: Unfortunately,I am not able to fully deliberate on the issues regarding both of your suggestions due to character limitations. However, I will exercise information from both of your suggestions to generate a new code. THANK YOU

Comment: @DirkReichel, both of your edits generate additional worksheets in all loops, however, I believe I can use your suggestions to develop a richer code. So, I thank you so very much for helping me. I am new to this forum how do I show appreciation to you within this forum? I really appreciate you.

Comment: @Liz both examples do exactly what they should do... still, I'm not sure what you exactly need.... but if you are able to develop it on your own, than that's better then any solution someone can offer... if you still need help, just ask :)

Comment: @DirkReichel, I have a requirement for when the user selects multiple items a workbook, only one workbook is produced that will have always contain Client_Profile. Your code: Private Sub CMDSubSelector_1_Click(), works beautifully for single select items. However, if index 0 and 1 are selected I need one workbook to be produced that contains:"Client_Profile", "SubmissionProperty", and "SubmissionLiabilty" sheets into one workbook. This is my struggle. I hope this better explains what I am seeking. Thank you ahead of time for further reviewing this!